# ImportError "Cannot import name Package1"

Tags: python, importerror

My directory structure is:

```
[File1]
    [Package1]
        __init__.py
            from Package1 import module1
            from Package1 import module2
            ...
        module1.py
        module2.py
        ...
```

I want to import a package so that using a class like

```
from File1 import Package1 
Package1.Module1.Class1()…
```

is possible.
When I try

```
from File1 import Package1
```

I always get the error:

```
cannot import name Package1
```

I think that Circular imports may be the problem, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Which Python version? Also, is `File1` a package as well (meaning, does it contain an `__init__.py`)? And from where do you try this import, the python shell or another file?

Comment: I use Python 3.3. At the moment File1 is not a package. I try to import from the python shell.

Comment: For your import to work, the `File1` folder needs to be a package too (or you need to import `Package1` from inside of the `File1` directory). I guess you have a python _module_ `File1.py` as the import only fails on `Package1`.

Comment: If i add __init__.py to File1 it still doesn't work. Does it matter if __init__.py is empty or not?

Answer (score 0):

1) You need to add `__init__()` in `File1` folder also (empty also ok).

2) Change `__init__()` inside `Package1` as follows:

```
__init__.py
from File1.Package1 import module1
from File1.Package1 import module2
```

Then from your python file you can access like

```
from File1 import Package1
x=Package1.module1()
x=Package1.module2()
```

I think this will work....
have fun